# Swapfunction and functions in general

Tags: c, swap

I'm trying my luck at this swap function but I'm having problems.

My hope is that the "new num1" should be swapped for the value of num2, and vice versa.

Can anyone shove me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>


void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
int temp = *a;
a = *b;
b = temp;
printf("Just checking if this badboy gets to the swapfunction.\n");
}


int main()
{
int num1 = 33;
int num2 = 45;

swap(&num1, &num2);

printf("A: %d\n", num1);
printf("B: %d\n", num2);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should get error/warning messages from the compiler telling you what lines have a problem. If not then you need to look into what settings you're using with your compiler.

Comment: Hi, and thanks, it worked when I used the * in the right way.
No, it didn't warn me about that, it just printed out the original number in it's original order. Where can I manage settings like this?

Comment: depends what compiler and IDE you are using...

Comment: @niyz Which compiler/IDE/system/... are you using ? Any decent compiler should throw an error message such as `cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *deference* the pointers:

```
int temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
```

Didn't your compiler warn you?

Comment: Hi, and thanks, it worked when I used the * in the right way. No, it didn't warn me about that, it just printed out the original number in it's original order. Where can I manage settings like this?

Comment: If you are using GCC `-Wall` will enable all warnings. There are some finer grained options, see "warning options" here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Some important things you should know about is:

```
int temp = *a; // Correct , temp stores value at the address of a

a = *b; //Incorrect, a is pointer that is used to hold address NOT values
```

Correction required is:

```
*a = *b; //Correct, now value at address of a is = value at address of b
```

Same mistake here also:

```
b = temp;//Incorrect, cause b is pointer used to hold address and NOT values
```

Correction required is

```
*b = temp;
```